# SecurityConfiguration class has erros at securityFilterChain method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a spring boot JWT authentication and authorization app and I'm facing some errors at the class SecurityConfiguration which deals with the bean securityFilterChain. The code is here.

```
package com.daian.security.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authentificationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authentificationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I am working with Intellij. I get that authorizeHttpRequests(), and(), sessionManagement(), and() are deprecated and marked for removal. Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: Those aren't errors but warnings. If you read the documentation (the javadoc of the deprecated methods) it will explain exactly what you need to replace it with.